# How to Move text on navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar

Hi I have to move the text on navigation bar..I don't have any idea about scrolling text. Is anybody have idea about this please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You want to move text  on touch or automatically moving text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADD this files in to your project and import it in to your class then add the following command in your view did load.I hope You are using a navigation based template for your application.

http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/10/simple-scrolling-uilabel-for-iphone.html

and then in viewdidload

```
AutoScrollLabel *autoScrollLabel=[[AutoScrollLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 15, 320, 16)];
autoScrollLabel.text = @"Hi Mom!  How are you?  I really ought to write more often.";
autoScrollLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//self.title = @"Resources";
//self.title = @"%@"autoScrollLabel;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:autoScrollLabel];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to move label text exactly same like in iphone music player application. If yes then do the following.

```
1`. Download Marquee Label files from this link 'https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel'.`


2.   - (void)addMovingLabelText { 
            MarqueeLabel *_lectureName = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,200, 20) duration:5.0 andFadeLength:10.0f];
            [_lectureName setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
            [_lectureName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [_lectureName setText:@"I am a moving Label in iphone Application"];
            _lectureName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=NO;
            [_lectureName setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];
            [self.navigationItem setTitleView:_lectureName];
}

3. call addMovingLabelText from viewDidLoad
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, navbars can be customized with your own titleView, so all you need to do is create a view with the scrolling text inside. Because there is no component to achieve this effect in the SDK, you have to look for one in open-sourced libraries or create your own. I never used it, but take a look to this one [UIScrollingLabel](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/10/simple-scrolling-uilabel-for-iphone.html)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 approach with `MarqueeLabel`:

```
    let title = MarqueeLabel(frame: CGRect.zero, duration: 20, fadeLength: 10)
    title.textAlignment = .center
    title.textColor = .white
    title.text = header

    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = title
```